# How to fetch sdcard songs in listview and display in listview in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-mediaplayer

I have written this code but while I have launched the application it's unfortunately stopped. I am using Android Studio.

```
public class AllMusicDemo extends AppCompatActivity {
    String []album;
    String []name;
    String []concat;
    ListView listmusic;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_music_demo);
        listmusic= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listmusic);
        Uri uri= MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        Cursor cursor= getContentResolver().query(uri,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.COMPOSER,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA}
        , null, null, null);
        album=new String[cursor.getCount()];
        name=new String[cursor.getCount()];
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for (int i= 0; i< cursor.getCount(); i++){


            album[i]= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
            name[i]=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
            concat[i]=album[i]+"   "+name[i];
             cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(AllMusicDemo.this, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,concat);
        listmusic.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide stacktrace of app crash you are talking about.

Comment: `sdcard songs in listview and display in listview`. You have two listviews?

Comment: please check this line of code cursor.getCount(); it the count is 0 it means loop iteration is not iterating that is causing concat [] array initialization

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: @Abdul so, i have to also initalized the concat[] with new String[cursor.getCount()].

Comment: @greenapps no i have only one listview that name is listmusic

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of songs like this :

```
public static ArrayList<MediaItem> listOfSongs(Context context){
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0", null, null);
        ArrayList<MediaItem> listOfSongs = new ArrayList<MediaItem>();
        c.moveToFirst();
        while(!c.isAfterLast()){
            MediaItem songData = new MediaItem();

            String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
            String artist = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
            String album = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
            long duration = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));
            String data = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
            long albumId = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
            String composer = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.COMPOSER));

            songData.setTitle(title);
            songData.setAlbum(album);
            songData.setArtist(artist);
            songData.setDuration(duration);
            songData.setPath(data);
            songData.setAlbumId(albumId);
            songData.setComposer(composer);
            listOfSongs.add(songData);

            c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();
        Log.d("SIZE", "SIZE: " + listOfSongs.size());
        return listOfSongs;
    }
```

where MediaItem is a class which holds your song details :

```
public class MediaItem {
    String title;
    String artist;
    String album;
    String path;
    long duration;
    long albumId;
    String composer;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getAlbum() {
        return album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(String album) {
        this.album = album;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public long getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(long duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public long getAlbumId() {
        return albumId;
    }

    public void setAlbumId(long albumId) {
        this.albumId = albumId;
    }

    public String getComposer() {
        return composer;
    }

    public void setComposer(String composer) {
        this.composer = composer;
    }
}
```

Now you just need to bind the list of songs received to your adapter class.